# Django 2.0 Internationalization | i18n_patterns not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, internationalization, upgrade

I have been working with i18n so that the URL included the prefix "/en/" or "/es/" depending on the users preferred language.

So far it was working fine while using Django 1.9 it even placed automatically the prefix even when the user didn't submit it in the URL (i.e. mySite.com would redirect to mySite.com/en/).

Now that I upgraded to 2.0 it is not working and it shows a 404 error:

> Using the URLconf defined in smce.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> en/
>
> ^static/(?P.*)$
>
> ^images/(?P.*)$
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these.

At my root urls.py i have:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('login/', anonymous_required(views.login), {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),

    path('', include('matrix.urls'), name='matrix'),
)
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: did you set `prefix_default_language=False ` and LANGUAGE_CODE='en',

Comment: Great! that fixed the issue. thanks!
do you mind to answer so I can accept it?

Comment: sure @izuzvo, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving this problem just set these configs in settings.py

```
  LANGUAGE_CODE='en'
  prefix_default_language=False
```

Comment: prefix_default_language should be set in the root urls.py, inside i18n_patterns, not settings.py or admin.py. LANGUAGE_CODE should be set in settings.py, not admin.py.